# 3D plot in maplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to visualize 3D surface using Matplolib. 
I got a RESULTS.csv file with results:

```
T1,T2,Energy
0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,0.0,-1.0,0.02326751
2,0.0,1.0,0.0232677
3,0.0,-2.0,0.09329646
4,0.0,2.0,0.0932964
5,0.0,-3.0,0.20991799
6,0.0,3.0,0.2099179
7,0.0,-4.0,0.37299244
8,0.0,4.0,0.37299269
9,0.0,-5.0,0.58232459
10,0.0,5.0,0.58232482
11,0.0,-6.0,0.83765862
12,0.0,6.0,0.83765867
13,-1.0,0.0,0.02297095
14,1.0,0.0,0.02297112
15,-1.0,-1.0,0.09457491
16,-1.0,1.0,-0.00195612
17,1.0,-1.0,-0.00195583
18,1.0,1.0,0.09457513
19,-1.0,-2.0,0.21270257
20,-1.0,2.0,0.01988884
21,1.0,-2.0,0.01988887
22,1.0,2.0,0.21270261
23,-1.0,-3.0,0.37714697
24,-1.0,3.0,0.08936601
25,1.0,-3.0,0.08936597
26,1.0,3.0,0.37714726
27,-1.0,-4.0,0.58764634
28,-1.0,4.0,0.20399978
29,1.0,-4.0,0.20399997
30,1.0,4.0,0.58764618
```

Subsequently, I wrote a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


FRAME =  pd.read_csv('RESULTS.csv')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-4, 4, 1.0)
xlen = len(X)
Y = np.arange(-4, 4, 1.0)
ylen = len(Y)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.array(FRAME['Energy'])

colortuple = ('y', 'b')
colors = np.empty(X.shape, dtype=str)
for y in range(ylen):
    for x in range(xlen):
        colors[x, y] = colortuple[(x + y) % len(colortuple)]

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=colors,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(6))

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work in an expecting way and am getting the following error in return:

```
File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1586, in plot_surface
    X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 191, in broadcast_arrays
    shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 126, in _broadcast_shape
    b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Any tips how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you need this buggy "pandas"-module at all?**

Everytime I see someone perform "pandas" operations together with numpy and matplotlib there appear absurd errors..

If you read your .csv-file conventionally with **xlrd** and add each cell value to a numpy array, and all 3 arrays "X", "Y" and "Z" have same length, there is no problem plotting it...

See matplotlib example 
http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

print len(X)
print len(Y)
print len(Z) #all 3 arrays must have same length!

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```